# Use looped array to take in string inputs

Tags: c#

I am looking to find a way to take assign the value of user inputs to the variables I have, but to use a loop to take this entry and position it on the screen. Is there a way to do this?

Below is my non-working code but hopefully it should provide an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

```
public void StudentDetailInput()
    {
        const int startpoint = 2;
        string[] takeinput = new string[] {FirstName, Surname, MiddleName, StudentId, Subject, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, Town, Postcode, Telephone, Email };

        for (int x = 0; x < takeinput.Length; x++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(30, startpoint + x);
            [x] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to follow a basic tutorial about C#.

Comment: Thank you mert for that very helpful input.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use a Dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _answers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public void StudentDetailInput()
{
    string[] takeinput = new string[] { 
        "FirstName", 
        "Surname",
        "MiddleName",
        "StudentId",
        "Subject",
        "AddressLine1", 
        "AddressLine2",
        "Town", 
        "Postcode", 
        "Telephone",
        "Email" 
    };

    _answers.Clear();
    for (int x = 0; x < takeinput.Length; x++)
    {
        Console.Write(takeinput[x] + ": ");
        var answer = Console.ReadLine();
        _answers.Add(takeinput[x], answer);

    }
}
```

So you can display the answers like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < _answers.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", _answers.Keys[i], _answers.Values[i]);
}
```

If your concern is that you do not want to use this many lines on the console you could keep track of the length of the answers and try to put the cursor right behind the answers so far. The problem with this is that you'll need to take the screen's width (which can be adjusted by the user) into account to calculate the correct line and position.

Another issue with this construction will be that users will expect the cursor to go one line down (that is what enter does) so the user experience might suffer.

An alternative would be to clear the screen after each input, display all answers so far starting at line 2 of the console and positioning the next question on line one:

```
for (int x = 0; x < takeinput.Length; x++)
{
    Console.Clear();
    for(y = 0; y < x; y++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, y + 1);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", _answers.Keys[y], _answers.Values[y]);
    }
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.Write(takeinput[x] + ": ");
    var answer = Console.ReadLine();
    _answers.Add(takeinput[x], answer);
}
```

This might go horribly wrong when the number of questions is more than the number of lines on the console.

Comment: I added a solution for keeping the cursor at the top line.

Answer (score 1):

Your string array definition is not clear, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public void StudentDetailInput()
{
    const int startpoint = 2;
    string[] takeinput = new string[11];

    for (int x = 0; x < takeinput.Length; x++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, startpoint + x);
        takeinput[x] = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now

```
// FirstName = takeinput[0]
// Surname   = takeinput[1]
// ...
```

Comment: The problem with your method is that I am storing the student objects in a list and using the string variables for things such as searches. So another function would need the named variable called Surname as I use that to create a user search.

Comment: @MarkSearle Ok, That's a different question.

Comment: Is it possible? Its just to avoid the 22 lines of code filling each one and positioning it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong.

```
[x] = Console.ReadLine();
```

If you want to assign to your elements of array, what you read with `ReadLine()` method, you should use

```
takeinput[x] = Console.ReadLine();
```

If you just want to assign the counter what you read, you should use;

```
x = Convert.Int32(Console.ReadLine());
```

***EDIT***: If I understand your question clearly, you just want to this;

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
string input = "";

do
{
   input = Console.ReadLine();
   list.Add(input);
}
while (input != "exit");
list.Remove("exit");

foreach (var item in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to store the input in the variable rather then in an array, the array was just an attempt at being able to access the different variables in a loop. (I am not too good explaining myself hope this makes sense)

Comment: @MarkSearle Are you try to store your more than one input with using `Console.ReadLine()`? For example, in a `while` statement?

Comment: I am having difficulty explaining myself. It is just an attempt at shortening my code and using a loop to fill the variables rather then listing them one by one.

Comment: Actually my program is storing the student object into a list later, this was just trying to find a quicker way to take the user inputs and place then in the various named string variables. Your post has helped though I will try something else based on your suggestion. Thank you